# NPM install doesn't install all components, node-gyp fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose, npm

I'm using ubuntu server 14.04.1 LTS which I believe to be an x32 machine

When trying to run my nodejs instance I get an error

`{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version`

Please **do not** link answers related to the above problem here. The problem is not it failing to load. **It just isn't installed.** Here is my package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "socket.io": "*",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoose": "*"
}
```

When I run **sudo npm install** (npm is in the latest version) I get the following:

```
npm WARN package.json forum@0.0.1 No description
npm WARN package.json forum@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json forum@0.0.1 No README data
npm WARN engine express@4.12.3: wanted: {"node":">= 0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.5"})
npm WARN engine mongoose@4.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.6.19"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.5"})
(...)
npm WARN engine options@0.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=0.4.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.5"})
-
> ws@0.5.0 install /usr/share/nginx/www/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

npm WARN engine hooks-fixed@1.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.4.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.5"})
(...)
npm WARN engine base64-arraybuffer@0.1.2: wanted: {"node":">= 0.6.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.5"})

> kerberos@0.0.10 install /usr/share/nginx/www/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

npm WARN engine bson-ext@0.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.8.19"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.5"})
(...)
npm WARN engine tinycolor@0.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.4.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.5"})

> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/share/nginx/www/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

npm WARN engine bson@0.2.21: wanted: {"node":">=0.6.19"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.5"})

> bson-ext@0.1.0 install /usr/share/nginx/www/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


> kerberos@0.0.10 install /usr/share/nginx/www/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


> bson@0.2.21 install /usr/share/nginx/www/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


> bson@0.3.1 install /usr/share/nginx/www/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

In fact, none of those folders (bson, kerberos, ws) are found inside the node_modules subfolders. So it's really **MODULE_NOT_FOUND**.

I tried running **npm update**, does nothing, always repeats same output.
I tried doing **node-gyp rebuild**, here is the output:

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@1.0.3
gyp info using node@0.13.0-pre | linux | ia32
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed, use the --nodedir flag instead
gyp ERR! stack     at install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:66:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.self.commands.(anonymous function) [as install] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js:66:37)
gyp ERR! stack     at getNodeDir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:152:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:95:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:723:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1000:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1168:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.close (net.js:461:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-48-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/share/nginx/www
gyp ERR! node -v v0.13.0-pre
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
```

And I tried installing with node-gyp with -g, nothing worked.
This is getting to the point where I achieve beyond desperation.
Can anyone help me please? Thank you very much...

Comment: Your `node-gyp rebuild` isn't going to work with a pre-release version. So either get the latest stable release (which is 12.2 according to their site) or run `node-gyp rebuild --nodedir /path/to/install/node/to` and then add that to your path. Additionally, at one point you said you ran `sudo npm install` but further commends you omit the `sudo`. Make sure you're running commands consistently.

Answer (score 1):

In dependencies, remove mongodb. mongoose will install the driver inside it.

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "socket.io": "*",       
    "mongoose": "*"
}
```

then do

```
sudo npm unistall mongodb
sudo npm cache clean
sudo npm install
```

If the problem still persists, then do

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Also, always run the commands under sudo if you are not the root user.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding specific stable and compatible versions in your dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "mongodb": "^2.0.47",
    "mongoose": "^4.2.3",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.7"
}
```

If you are running `npm install` inside a project you shouldn't also run npm as `sudo`. If you don't do it `npm` should install your modules inside the project in the `node_modules` directory and you will be able to use different versions in each project.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me some times.

> Until now, clearing the npm cache was enough :

```
npm cache clean
npm i
```

> DO NOT use `sudo`! It is required to clear cache for global npm bins, not local, and also, not if you use nvm as normal user (for local and global packages)